# How to create perspective text around a circular shape in HTML?

Tags: html, css, text, rotation, transform

I have to do a web page with some perspective texts on it's menu and contents. Following is a link to an image of the effect I should achieve. Is it possible? Where to start? I'm clueless and don't even know what's the best to do. I appreciate any help.

http://goo.gl/Wlz5b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rotating text

If you just need to rotate text elements, that can be done with CSS3, using a [2D-transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/) [rotation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

Supporting IE8 and earlier would require using an [IE matrix filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (and some extra work to position the text correctly).

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EYtuS/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <p class="text text1">This is a short sentence.</p>
    <p class="text text2">This is a second sentence.</p>
    <p class="text text3">This is a third sentence.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
            transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
.text1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
            transform: rotate(-4deg);

}
.text3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
            transform: rotate(4deg);

}
```

### 3D rotation

If you need true 3D perspective (such that the text is larger on one end than the other), that will be tougher to manage cross-browser. The mock-up in the question doesn't appear to have 3D perspective.

Comment: Wow! Great! Thank you Matt! That's exactly what I needed! I'll try it out at my designs and let you know when it's finished!